# Are homotopy colimits strict?

Tags: enriched-category-theory, simplicial-categories, homotopy-limits

Let's say we are working with a fibrant simplicially enriched category $\mathbf{B}$ that has all limits and all homotopy limits, and let $\mathbf{A}$ be a full subcategory that is closed under weak equivalences (in the simplicially enriched sense).

1. Is it the case that a homotopy limit can be computed as the strict limit of a homotopy equivalent diagram? (In the style of model categories, where we first choose a suitable replacement diagram and then take the strict limit of that, as shown in Chapter 20 of [this book](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/dhks.pdf) in the fullest generality).
2. If I know that a certain diagram in $\mathbf{A}$ has a strict limit, is it true that an objectwise homotopy equivalent diagram also has a strict limit? (Remember that $\mathbf{B}$ has all of them by assumption, although the inclusion doesn't necessarily preserve them).
3. Both the above questions in a particularly explicit example, such as $\mathcal{sSet}^{\circ}$, i.e. the simplicial category of all Kan complexes.

This is possibly related to [another question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428239/homotopy-colimits-in-subcategories-of-combinatorial-model-categories?noredirect=1#comment1101428_428239).

Comment: Without additional assomption, that's probably false... are you willing to assume that for e.g. B has simplicially enriched limits (co-tensor)? That might help...

Comment: The point I'm getting at is that if homotopy limits in B can be described using a Bousfield-Kan formula, then at least in B homotopy limits are équivalent to strict limits of an equivalent diagram...

Comment: Yes I can assume tensors and cotensors. In fact, as a general guideline, I can have basically all sorts of nice assumptions on $\mathbf{B}$, but $\mathbf{A}$ should be as general as possible, except that I can close it under weak equivalences. I don't even want to assume completeness, or homotopy completeness on $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: I edited the question, asking if something can be said at least in the very special case of the category of fibrant objects in the classical model structure on simplicial sets.